# Ubuntu server 14.04 and Zimbra

Tags: mail-server, zimbra

What is correct full name for the server? It was "name.domain.com" and after installing Zimbra, general mail domain became "@name.domain.com". Is it correct? Or do I have to create another domain in Zimbra like "@domain.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct full server hostname or FQDN suppost to be something like server.domain.com

Ff your server's hostname is server, its FQDN is server.domain.com, 
then to you have to make sure `host -t mx domain.com` returns server.domain.com as MX record for domain.com